# How to calculate multiples of percentage value in SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a const value `$length: 12.5%`.

Also I have a list with different multipliers `$multipliers: ('1','2','3','4')`.

In `@each` I will be looping through all items in `$multipliers` and have to calculate the following formula.

FORMULA => `$length * $multiplier + 1`

```css
@each $multiplier in $multipliers {
  .item-#{$multiplier} {
     top: << FORMULA >>
  }
}
```

Can someone assist on how to calculate the top value in SCSS, which contains percentage?

Comment: just change 'of' to 'in' and try it seems to be working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [SCSS `@for` loop](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for).

```css
$length: 12.5%;

@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  .item-#{$i} {
    top: ($i * $length);
  }
}
```

It will generate this CSS:

```css
.item-1 {
  top: 12.5%;
}

.item-2 {
  top: 25%;
}

.item-3 {
  top: 37.5%;
}

.item-4 {
  top: 50%;
}
```

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/donroyco/pen/zYZzQer). Use the right top CSS dropdown menu to 'View Compiled CSS'.